# Which version of cordova is to be used while targeting Android 5.0?

Tags: cordova, android-5.0-lollipop, cordova-plugins

I'm building Cordova Android Apps with Intel XDK. I want to know which cordova version should I use while targeting for Android 5.0 apps?

Precisely, I want to use Cordova media API, the current version (3.5), I'm using is unstable with Android 5.0.

Comment: file an issue on the cordova jira page https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB/. But the music is killed from time to time on native apps to, seems more like an android 5 problem

Answer (score 1):

Currently is 3.6. It's already set to latest version when you create a new one.

Comment: Thanks, I just check Intel xdk doesn't support 3.6 version. The max version it supports is 3.5.1. The problem is when I'm using Cordova  media api, it works fine in Android 4.4.4, but with Android 5.0, the App gets killed after8-10 while playing music in background. Any idea, how to get rid of it?